# Excel VBA - more than 4 digits in data number causes script error

Tags: excel, vba

I have a script that loops through all the CSV files in a folder, imports the data into a master workbook, then closes and deletes the CSV file before moving on to the next. A portion of the data import sets some cells as a variable and then performs a calculation to get a new number, which is then posted into the workbook. I was having an issue with ONE of my CSVs giving me an error and I have narrowed it down to having to do with whether the data is more than 4 digits long. [This screenshot of the CSV shows what data is causing an error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObaHR.png) If I were to change the values by removing one digit from each of the highlighted cells, the CSV will import correctly. I don't know what's causing this or how to fix it. Changing the cell format to number/text/general/etc doesn't make a difference. The values of the cells themselves also do not contain the commas (the value is actually 9513, not 9,513)

Below is the excerpt from the script that deals with importing the CSV data:

```
'LOOP THROUGH FOLLOWING CODE IF A MATCH IS FOUND
    If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
        Dim table_list_object As ListObject
        Dim table_object_row As ListRow
        Set table_list_object = Workbooks("Spokes- Google Analytics trends.xlsm").Worksheets(sheet_name_result).ListObjects(1)
        Set table_object_row = table_list_object.ListRows.Add

    'calculate pageviews
        Dim organic_pageviews As Integer
        Dim paid_pageviews As Integer
        Dim direct_pageviews As Integer
        Dim referral_pageviews As Integer
        Dim display_pageviews As Integer
        Dim sum_pageviews As Integer
        organic_pageviews = Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), "organic", Range("C:C"))
        paid_pageviews = Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), "paid", Range("C:C"))
        direct_pageviews = Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), "direct", Range("C:C"))
        referral_pageviews = Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), "referral", Range("C:C"))
        display_pageviews = Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), "display", Range("C:C"))
        sum_pageviews = organic_pageviews + paid_pageviews + direct_pageviews + referral_pageviews + display_pageviews

    'calculate visitors aka sessions
        Dim organic_visitors As Integer
        Dim paid_visitors As Integer
        Dim direct_visitors As Integer
        Dim referral_visitors As Integer
        Dim display_visitors As Integer
        Dim sum_visitors As Integer
        organic_visitors = Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), "organic", Range("F:F"))
        paid_visitors = Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), "paid", Range("F:F"))
        direct_visitors = Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), "direct", Range("F:F"))
        referral_visitors = Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), "referral", Range("F:F"))
        display_visitors = Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), "display", Range("F:F"))
        sum_visitors = organic_visitors + paid_visitors + direct_visitors + referral_visitors + display_visitors

    'calculate unique visitors aka new users
        Dim organic_new As Integer
        Dim paid_new As Integer
        Dim direct_new As Integer
        Dim referral_new As Integer
        Dim display_new As Integer
        Dim sum_new As Integer
        organic_new = Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), "organic", Range("E:E"))
        paid_new = Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), "paid", Range("E:E"))
        direct_new = Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), "direct", Range("E:E"))
        referral_new = Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), "referral", Range("E:E"))
        display_new = Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), "display", Range("E:E"))
        sum_new = organic_new + paid_new + direct_new + referral_new + display_new

    'calculate pages/visit
        Dim pages_per_visit As String
        pages_per_visit = (sum_pageviews / sum_visitors) / 100
    'calculate organic traffic
        Dim organic_percent As String
        organic_percent = (organic_visitors / sum_visitors)

    'calculate referral traffic
        Dim referral_percent As String
        referral_percent = (referral_visitors / sum_visitors)

    'isolate start date
        Dim date_location As String
        Dim start_date_ugly As String
        Dim start_date_string As String

        date_location = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A4")
        start_date_ugly = Left(date_location, 10)
        start_date_string = Right(start_date_ugly, 8)

    'isolate end date
        Dim end_date_string As String

        end_date_string = Right(date_location, 8)

    'posts data to columns
        table_object_row.Range(1, 1).Value = DateSerial(Left(start_date_string, 4), Mid(start_date_string, 5, 2), Right(start_date_string, 2))
            table_object_row.Range(1, 1).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
        table_object_row.Range(1, 2).Value = DateSerial(Left(end_date_string, 4), Mid(end_date_string, 5, 2), Right(end_date_string, 2))
            table_object_row.Range(1, 2).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
        table_object_row.Range(1, 3).Value = sum_pageviews
        table_object_row.Range(1, 4).Value = sum_visitors
        table_object_row.Range(1, 5).Value = sum_new
        table_object_row.Range(1, 6).Value = Format((pages_per_visit), Percent)
        table_object_row.Range(1, 7).Value = organic_percent
        table_object_row.Range(1, 8).Value = referral_percent
```

Comment: Do you mean more than 4 *characters*? (counting the comma as a character, because none of the highlighted cells contain more than 4 *digits*).

Comment: Also, you might want to indicate which line causes the error, and specifically what error message is?

Comment: I mean that if the number in the cell is 111 it will work, but if it's 1111 it won't work. The actual value of the cell doesn't contain the comma, that's just displaying from the number format that was automatically applied. The script is actually part of a larger script that has an error message box set, so the custom message is the response I'm getting, not an excel error code. Let me remove the message box and see what the default excel response is

Comment: I'm betting it's Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overflow error is apparent from the screenshot data.

[Read up on the limitations of Integer data type:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa164754.aspx)

> Integer variables can hold values between -32,768 and 32,767, while Long variables can range from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647

In your case, the sum of several integers can exceed the allowable values for your `Integer` variables. Change all of your `As Integer` declarations to `As Long`.

Try this to illustrate it

```
Sub f()
    Dim x As Integer, y As Integer, z As Integer
    x = 9000
    y = 23767
    z = x + y
    MsgBox z

    MsgBox z + 1  '## Now we're over the limit of Integer type, this line will error

End Sub
```

There also seems to be something tricky about arithmetic with Integer type -- namely: ifyou're adding several values together and *any one of them* are `Integer` type, VBA expects the return value to also be an integer. Sometimes this is not a problem, but when dealing with larger numbers it often is, so if you do:

```
val = 6 + 32767 'This will also raise an error!
val = 32767 + 64738 'This will NOT error!
```

You need to coerce integers to `Long` and you can do this using `CLng` function:

```
val = CLng(6) + 32767
```

Comment: You hit the nail right on the head! I had no idea that there was a limit for Integers vs Long types, that's good to know going forward in case I'm working with either again. Thank you for the explanation and example!
Also, from the link you posted it looks like Integer is maybe being slowly phased out, since VBA converts them all to Long in recent versions. I wonder if eventually this won't be an issue any more.

Comment: Nice writeup here, David. Covers all the bases, and illustrates it very clearly!